# Appendices with elsarticle

Tags: floats, elsarticle

I am writing an article in LaTeX with document class `elsarticle`. When I type my appendix as follows, it changes all the figure and table captions in previous sections as Table A.1, Table A.2, Figure A.1 Figure A.2,... etc. which are not under section appendix.

```
\appendix
\section{Appendix name}
\begin{table}[ht]
.
.
.
.
\end{table}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information both about your TeX distribution and about your specific document setup. The reason I ask for this information is that I am unable to replicate the issue you describe with my TeX distribution (MacTeX2020, all updates applied; elsarticle class v3.2 2019/02/25) and a simple test document.

Comment: I am using overleaf.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Please make a minimal example starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think I could find the reason for the issue. that is because of the use of endfloat package. it lists all figures and tables at the end of the document and changes the labels to appendix labels. Thanks all for your consideration.